# Inno Setup is stretching progress style

Tags: inno-setup, vcl-styles

I'm using a custom VCL style, Its progress bar image is like windows XP.
But While installing and using the style, inno setup will stretch the progress image into the progress bar.

How to avoid such an effect?

[image]

Comment: This is really strange, there is no such behavior on Windows. Can you post some sample script so we can test that?

Comment: @Slappy just try a VCL style and you will see all of the progress images are like that. They will stretch. just try to change the progress image to what it is looking in the image. you will get the same result.